# How to properly handle empty resultset with Hibernate and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a Spring app that is using Hibernate and the Spring Data JPA's `CrudRepository`. Everything seems to work properly if the data that was queried for exists in the database. However, if there is a query that returns no result, the `CrudRepository` returns `null` and I get a `NullPointerException`. So for example `http://localhost:8080/api/id=3` if there is a row with id 3 in the database it works fine. If there isn't a row with id of 3 it fails with a:

> there was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500)

On the client side and a `NullPointerException` on the server side.

What is the proper way of dealing with a simple case of a "No Results" query?

Comment: return a 404 Not Found.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your approach?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Inspect the return value, if it's not `null`, return some representation of it as a `200 OK` response. Otherwise, return a `404 Not Found`. In the end, you would have a controller like:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public ResponseEntity<?> getOne(...) {
    Something something = repository.findOne(...);
    if (something == null)
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();

    return ResponseEntity.ok(something);
}
```

---

You can refactor the preceding code to incorporate Java 8's `Optional<T>`, as [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757048/how-to-properly-handle-empty-resultset-with-hibernate-and-spring-boot#comment62984085_37757236). Basically, `Optional<T>` is just a container that may or may not hold a value of type `T`. You can use this type as the return type of Spring Data JPA methods, something like the following:

```
public interface SomethingRepository extends CrudRepository<Something, Long> {
    Optional<Something> findById(Long id);
}
```

Then define one exception for `404 Not Found`:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class NotFoundException extends RuntimeException {}
```

If you throw an exception of type `NotFoundException` in your controllers, Spring MVC's exception resolver would catch that exception and convert it to a `404 Not Found` HTTP response.

Finally your controller would be like:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public Something getOne(...) {
    return repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);
}
```

---

For more detailed discussions on:

- Spring Data JPA's `Optional<T>` support, [read here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#_supported_query_return_types).
- Spring MVC's exception resolvers, [read here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-exceptionhandlers).
- Java 8's `Optional<T>`, [read here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjcgcfmt57NAhVFnRoKHS9qB3YQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F8%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Futil%2FOptional.html&usg=AFQjCNHjGZGPnR1RNdg8kGzc-jb2jOhKFA&sig2=wWKYfzu3nSGT08ETDzaUoA&bvm=bv.124272578,d.ZGg).
- REST best practices, you can check out the [REST in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805829) book.

Comment: Or you can throw an exception and have some exception annotated with `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)`. Combined with the possibility for Spring-data-jpa to return an empty Optional rather than null, you can use: `Something something = somethingRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);`

Comment: @JBNizet Yeap, that's a great idea.

Comment: @JBNizet Updated the answer with your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, That worked. Would it be better to place the "@ResponseStatus" and "@RequestMapping" at my controller layer or my services layer?

Comment: It's better to not expose controller-specific stuff into your service layer

Comment: those who can searching the mentioned book REST best practices, can be download from link: https://github.com/transidai1705/java-ebooks/blob/master/%5BREST%20in%20Practice%20Hypermedia%20and%20Systems%20Architecture%20Kindle%20Edition%20by%20Ian%20Robinson%20-%202010%5D.pdf

Answer (score 1):

None of the spring crud repository find methods throw an exception if no results are returned. They all return nulls. Since you are getting a null pointer exception on the server side you must be trying to perform an operation on the returned value without checking whether it's null first.