# Spring JPA Create ResponseEntity from findById()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-jpa

In a spring boot application, I have an endpoint that returns a HTTP 200 response with an object if it exists, or a HTTP 404 reponse if not. Using spring-boot-starter-parent 1.5.7 I used to do that like this:

```
@Autowired private GroceryRepository groceryRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/get/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public ResponseEntity<Object> get(@PathVariable final Integer id) {
    final Grocery grocery = groceryRepository.findOne(id);
    if (null == grocery) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                .body(MessageUtil.parse(MSG_404_GROCERY, id + ""));
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(grocery);
}

GroceryRepository extends JpaRepository<Grocery, Integer>
```

In spring-boot-starter-parent 2.0.0, `findOne()` has disappeared from JpaRepository, and `findById()` returns an `Optional`. I'm struggling a bit on how to 'port' the above code. The following doesn't build, since it has an unexpected return type:

```
groceryRepository.findById(id).ifPresent(grocery -> {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(grocery);
});
```

Can someone tell me what would be the proper way of returning the right Response?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what error exactly you are getting

Comment: Compilation fails with "Incompatible types: unexpected return value"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ifPresent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-) has a `void` return type so performing `return ResponseEntity.ok(grocery);` will not work as you've already witnessed.

That said, Optional has an [isPresent()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent--) method which you can use:

```
Optional<Grocery> groceryOptional = groceryRepository.findById(id);
if(groceryOptional.isPresent()){
    return ResponseEntity.ok(groceryOptional.get());
}else {
    return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
            .body(MessageUtil.parse(MSG_404_GROCERY, id + ""));
}
```

Another approach would be:

```
Optional<Grocery> groceryOptional = groceryRepository.findById(id);
 return groceryOptional.map(e -> ResponseEntity.ok(e))
                       .orElse(ResponseEntity
                              .status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                              .body(MessageUtil.parse(MSG_404_GROCERY, id + "")));
```

Comment: The first approach works perfectly, but your second approach feels better, since it uses more of the Java 8 syntax. Thanks!

Comment: Where is MSG_404_GROCERY coming from and what is it? @ousmane-d

Answer (score 3):

Even though the above answer is correct I would go for an even better more functional solution.

Instead of calling `Optional#isPresent` to check whether the `Grocery` object is present I would something like:

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> get(@PathVariable final Integer id) {
    return groceryRepository.findOne(id)
                            .map(g -> ResponseEntity.ok(g))
                            .orElse(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(MessageUtil.parse(MSG_404_GROCERY, id + ""));

}
```

Comment: If I replace findOne() with "findById()", it fails to compile with "incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds". Can you explain how you meant this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found workaround for your issue in the following Stackoverflow link

[How to properly handle empty resultset with Hibernate and Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757048/how-to-properly-handle-empty-resultset-with-hibernate-and-spring-boot)
It has a neatly designed solution for this!
Hope it will help!